# How to Add Scripts to Path?

Tags: windows-8, script, powershell, path

I've stored commonly used powershell scripts at `%USERPROFILE%\Bin`. I created a `USER_BIN` environment variable which I added to the user `PATH` environment variable via `Control Panel > System and Security >  System > Advanced system setting > Environment Variables`.

When I enter the name of a script stored in `Bin`, i.e. `my-script.ps1`, into a cmd or powershell prompt I get the message `my-script.ps1 : The term 'my-script.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

If I provide the full-path, i.e. `C:\Users\Ari\Bin\my-script.ps1` the script works fine.

Comment: Programs load env variables on startup, have you restarted the application you're using to launch those scripts?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, I've restarted the apps, which are `cmd.exe` & `powershell.exe` respectively.

Comment: How _exactly_ did you add them to the Path?  How _exactly_ are you trying to run them, and what happens when you do?

Answer (score 3):

It's a powershell security feature. You can only invoke scripts by relative or absolute path but not by file name.

> To run a script, type the path and name of the script file. The path
>   is required, even when the script is located in the current directory,
>   to make it more difficult for malicious code to run scripts. The file
>   name extension is optional and, as always, Windows PowerShell is not
>   case sensitive.

The reasoning behind this decision is as follows:

> One trick malicious users commonly attempt in other shells is creating
>   a script with the same file name as a built-in command. So, for
>   example, if you wanted a user to run your script, you might name it
>   Dir.ps1 and drop it into a folder. If you convinced the user to type
>   Dir and press Enter, your script could run, not the Dir command the
>   user was expecting. This technique is called command hijacking. In
>   Windows PowerShell, you must always provide a path to such a script,
>   making Windows PowerShell pretty well protected against command
>   hijacking. Running demo1 doesn't work, since there's no path, but
>   running ./demo1 does work. This is because I've now specified a
>   path—the current folder. That command line is less likely to be
>   confused with a built-in command since you'd never type any kind of
>   path if you were referring to a built-in command. Thus, requiring a
>   path helps Windows PowerShell avoid command hijacking and confusion
>   over what might happen when you press Enter.

Sources: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.09.powershell.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Workaround: Have a .bat file in path call the ps1 script

Answer (score 0):

Windows initializes the Path for CMD and Powershell on login.  You'll need to log off and back on before either will check the new directories.

Comment: Thanks. But logging off & then back on did not work.